# Пытаемся установить патч сервере проекта Microsoft 2007 - "Установка не удалась"

Tags: sharepoint, project

Мы с коллегами пытаемся установить патч [KB968850](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/968850) на сервере проекта Microsoft 2007 и каждый раз мы получаем следующую ошибку:

> Обнаружение не удалось, это может быть из-за поврежденной базы данных по установке.

Когда мы пытаемся установить все исправления мы получаем ту же ошибку. Когда мы смотрели окно просмотра событий, то получали:

- идентификатор события, код события: 11708,
- источник: msiinstaller,
- описание: Microsoft Office Server Application Project Server — Установка не удалась.

Чем может быть вызвана данная ошибка?